# S9/S9+ specific WebView device crash report

Tags: android, webview, crash, crash-reports

We have been seeing crash reports coming into Google Play which are specific to the Samsung S9 (starqlesq) & S9+ (star2qlesq), both running Android 8.0.0:

`signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000a51278  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN13ShaderObjects17loadProgramBinaryEP15CompilerContextPvmP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+1396)
  #01  pc 000000000099b500  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN15CompilerContext17loadProgramBinaryEPvmP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+160)
  #02  pc 0000000000a6e110  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (_Z21QGLCLoadProgramBinaryPvS_mP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+88)
  #03  pc 00000000001a501c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN17EsxShaderCompiler21LoadProgramBinaryBlobEP10EsxContextP10EsxProgramPKvmP10EsxInfoLog+256)`

Looking at the above stack trace, the crash appears to be in OpenGL system code.

This is strange, because we have a crash reporting solution integrated (the Microsoft App Center SDK) and other crash reports are going to App Center.

Our app makes heavy use of `WebView`, which I understand now uses Chrome, running in a separate process.

My questions are therefore:

- Is the fact this crash report is going to Google Play and not App Center indicative of a `WebView` related crash?
- What sort of thing can cause a crash like this? So far it is affecting 3 unique users, so it doesn't appear to be specific to an individual user with an unusual device configuration.
- What actions would be most effective in narrowing down and resolving the issue?

Comment: We are also seeing similar crash reported on play store and all crashes are reported for Samsung Galaxy S9 and S9+ devices.

And the crash seems sporadic, It's not happening on all S9 and S9+ devices. 
We are suspecting new phone gpu driver may be at fault. At moment, we don't know how to address it.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue on the EMEA version of the S9/S9+, but know this is happening to someone in the US, probably with the US version of the S9/S9+, which has an entirely different processor core.

Comment: @LUMICYAN does your app use a WebView

Comment: Yes, it uses webview extensively.

Comment: @LUMICYAN I'm wondering if disabling hardware acceleration might work around the issue on these devices via `WebView.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)`? Obviously there would be a performance tradeoff, but preferable to crashing out.

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration is a big change especially when app is in production. And we don't know what are other consequences. I looked at samsung and qualcomm developer forum to see any mention of this crash. I didn't find any relevant posts.

Comment: Agreed - the whole situation is far from ideal but I'm not sure what other options are open to us at this point. I would only recommend disabling hardware acceleration for these specific devices

Comment: @LUMICYAN have you worked out any other factors in reproducing this issue? I'm unable to reproduce using a US S9 or S9+ via Sigos/Device Anywhere.

Comment: We are also unable to reproduce the crash with a test device. But i see more crashes are being reported on google play console.

Comment: As more data is coming in, it's becoming clear this problem is only affecting some starqltesq & star2qltesq devices.

We know that one of the devices experiencing this issue has a very slightly different build number and was a complimentary device provided direct from Samsung.

Our current working theory is these problematic complimentary devices are pre-production or contain pre-launch software builds.

Can anyone confirm commonality here?

Comment: We are seeing crashes on following devices.                  
Galaxy S9+ (star2qltesq) (16 crashes) 
Galaxy S9 (starqltesq) (9 crashes) 
Galaxy S9+ (star2qlteue) (1 crash)

Comment: It looks quite evident. May i know how did you find they are complimentary devices.

Comment: We had a direct bug report from a client of our organisation who happened to have one of these problematic devices. Unfortunately I'm not in direct contact, but we are going to try getting them to sideload an APK with hardware acceleration disabled on the `WebView` to see if that fixes it. Will report back when I know more.

Comment: We see this issue on at least 5 S9 devices:  star2qltesq, starqltesq, star2qlteue, starqlteue, the majority for the first two, and 520 crashes for Other.

Comment: Does anyone have clarity on why this crash doesn't get reported to App Center?  We also use App Center, and it also was not reported.

Comment: As [@GaryBak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155415/gary-bak), same problem, same devices. 2 months ago, I disabled Fyber's Mediation Ads in aforementioned devices to ***bypass*** the problem. Checked it again last week, but it still happens. So, off with the ads again.

Comment: Still having the same exact problem (Xamarin Platform apps). Would like to see a fix for this :(

Comment: Did anyone ever find a proper solution to this? I'm encountering this problem too, except with FirebaseUI and a drawing canvas error only on some Samsung devices. (Not explicitly a webview)

Comment: I never did find a better solution - I suspect the root cause is an OpenGLES driver bug, which is triggered by hardware acceleration for certain commands. I posted on the Samsung Developers forum but never got a response: https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=348226&startId=00s6Z~&startPage=6&curPage=8

Comment: @Mr.Drew you might get some clues for a fix for this issue in libgdx: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/3790

Comment: Hmm, mine is a slightly different problem now that I've been able to get the logs from the crashes. The same devices are crashing when drawing one of my bitmap resources, not webview or the sort. But it does sound like it could be a graphics driver thing for it to only be in this subset of devices.

Comment: @Mr.Drew agreed - route to experiencing the problem is different, but I believe the underlying cause is likely similar. I would be genuinely interested to know how you manage to solve this - they might even be a potential WebKit fix to be had out of it.

Comment: So it's 2020, has anyone found any solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling hardware acceleration has now been confirmed as working around the issue on these problematic devices:

```
val product = Build.PRODUCT
val s9ProductsThatNeedWorkaround = arrayOf("starqltesq", "star2qltesq", "starqlteue", "star2qlteue")
if (s9ProductsThatNeedWorkaround.contains(product)) {
    WebView.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)
}
```

There may be some cosmetic anomalies when rending web content however.

Comment: Did you disable hardware acceleration only for the affected devices, or for all devices?  If you targeted just those with this issue, could you include a code sample for effective device targeting in your answer?

Comment: Disabling the Chrome app helped me replicate this issue (this will cause a different version of WebView to be used). Seems like the perfect storm of 1) Android System WebView version, 2) Samsung update version, and 3) showing content in a WebView. Applying Andrew's workaround prevented the crash in my case.

Comment: @AdamTerlson where can I disable the hardware acceleration in the react-native application