# App crashing react native on Samsung Galaxy S9+ (star2qltesq), Android 8.0

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have released an app to the play store using react native and its working fine but I got a crash with the following log in play console and I'm not sure what to make of it. The crash happens on Samsung Galaxy S9+ (star2qltesq) running Android 8.0

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000001a6f0  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+11)
  #01  pc 0000000000761c39  /vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN14MetaDataExport19duplicateSymbolDataEP20QGLC_GLSL_SYMBOLDATAPKS0_+208)
  #02  pc 0000000000766d87  /vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN13ShaderObjects17loadProgramBinaryEP15CompilerContextPvjP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+1486)
  #03  pc 00000000006e5495  /vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN15CompilerContext17loadProgramBinaryEPvjP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+108)
  #04  pc 00000000007787c1  /vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (_Z21QGLCLoadProgramBinaryPvS_jP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+52)
  #05  pc 0000000000152023  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN17EsxShaderCompiler21LoadProgramBinaryBlobEP10EsxContextP10EsxProgramPKvjP10EsxInfoLog+170)
  #06  pc 000000000013490d  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxProgram17LoadProgramBinaryEP10EsxContextjPKvi+158)
  #07  pc 00000000000ac389  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN10EsxContext15GlProgramBinaryEjjPKvi+134)
  #08  pc 0000000000097553  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glProgramBinary+42)
  #09  pc 00000000017491ff  /data/app/com.android.chrome-HHWtCaxowbzF03n80oXarQ==/base.apk
```

Here is a snippet from app/build.gradle file

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxxx.xxx"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode x
        versionName "x.x.x"

        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libimagepipeline.so"
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true
            include "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride = versionCodes.get(abi) * 300000 + variant.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update

Upon further research it seems to be an issue with this specific device running a certain build. You can check out [S9/S9+ specific WebView device crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645746/s9-s9-specific-webview-device-crash-report) for more info.
There were issues created on samsung forums which have not got any response yet

[Issue 1](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=299236&startId=zzzzz~)

[Issue 2](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=348226&startId=00jZ7~&startPage=6&curPage=8)

The solution according to the stackoverflow post linked above is to disable `hardware acceleration` for webview. I'm not using an webview in the react native app but considering react native is written in js which is probably running a chromium instance, does the same logic apply? If so, how do you disable hardware acceleration in react native?

Comment: Hi. Any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, did you also face the same issue?

Comment: I'm fixed. But i don't know its same error. 
<project>/android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
add ```<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>```