# Release app for a specific phone on the play store

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

I would like to be able to release a version of the app only for a specific phone on the production channel in the play store, I know that it is possible to use beta and alpha channels to do this but a single user on the production channel is facing an issue with the current app version and I would like to revert that user to an older working version for the time being, how can I do that?

I know it's possible to do abi splits based on cpu architecture and screen size but that doesn't narrow it down enough to a specific device.

Comment: feel free to contact with google customer suppport

Comment: why do you want to do this in the first place? Can you not fix the issue?

Comment: This isn't possible.  Your best bet is to send him an older apk via email to sideload.

Comment: @TimCastelijns The app is designed using react native and the issue I am facing seems to be one with react native itself but only seems to be affecting this one specific phone with a specific build, I have used firebase test labs with the same phone and it works fine, so not having access to this specific device is making it difficult, I would be glad if you can help me out in anyway with the issue that I'm facing here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51356215/app-crashing-react-native-on-samsung-galaxy-s9-star2qltesq-android-8-0

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks, I'm keeping that as the last resort.

Comment: I think upload a "fix" to only 1 device in the case you could is a bad practice. You could fix it to the device in question and launch it to production, I mean, the fix shouldn't affect the other devices right? If it does you probably should think about the project structure and maybe in the las resort make a typical if else with the device like if (device is samsung s4) else ... I don't know if I have explained very good, sorry my english and get luck!