# Can't Understand Error/Crash provided by Google Play store

Tags: android, crash

My Android app is crashing and I am unable to understand the crash report provided by the play store. The report is:

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> MY PACKAGE NAME <<<

backtrace:   
#00  pc 0000000000a54ed4  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN13ShaderObjects17loadProgramBinaryEP15CompilerContextPvmP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+1112)
#01  pc 000000000099c8dc  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (_ZN15CompilerContext17loadProgramBinaryEPvmP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+160)
#02  pc 0000000000a725e8  /vendor/lib64/libllvm-glnext.so (_Z21QGLCLoadProgramBinaryPvS_mP23QGLC_LINKPROGRAM_RESULT+88)   
#03  pc 00000000001a73e0  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (_ZN17EsxShaderCompiler21LoadProgramBinaryBlobEP10EsxContextP10EsxProgramPKvmP10EsxInfoLog+256)
```

How can I understand this crash? Thanks.

Comment: That's a native crash. Does your app rely on native libraries? Is it only happening on one specific device?

Comment: May this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645746/s9-s9-specific-webview-device-crash-report) help you!

Comment: no, i don't use native libraries. This app is live wallpaper app. Currently this crash appeared on a specific device.

Comment: @SalmanKhalid Trying to reproduce the issue yourself is probably the best way if it's device-specific, that stacktrace doesn't tell us much, but the fact that it's a problem with libGLESv2 suggests it's a graphics driver issue with the device and something that may be out of your control. See if you've got a Device Lab nearby where you can test your app on the same device.

Comment: Thanks  Michael Dodd. I will try.